# Python: how to properly use apply()?

Tags: python, pandas, apply, geopandas

I have a geopandas dataframe that contains points

```
df:

        geometry
    0   POINT (806470.3646198167 2064879.919354021)
    1   POINT (792603.391127742 2170760.8355139)
    2   POINT (787263.3037740411 2050925.953643546)
    3   POINT (809203.6762813283 2160874.194588484)
    4   POINT (781668.2687635225 2051524.634389534)
```

for each point I would like to apply this function:

```
def returnValuePoints(df, i):
    points_list = [ (df['geometry'][i].x, df['geometry'][i].y) ] #list of X,Y coordinates
    for point in points_list:
        col = int((point[0] - xOrigin) / pixelWidth)
        row = int((yOrigin - point[1] ) / pixelHeight)
        return (row, col)
```

this what I am doing:

```
for i in df.index:
    val = returnValuePoints(df, data, i)
```

How can I avoid the loop and apply this function to all the rows with `apply()`

Comment: I think you probably don't want to be using apply here. There is probably a vectorized way to do this, but I don't know geopandas that well.

Comment: This looks like a combo of a reflection about the y-axis (though I wouldn't be surprised if that's an accident!), a translation by `xOrigin, yOrigin`, and a scaling factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to restructure your method so it takes values which you can pass using the lambda function within the apply (think of how you would want to operate on the values of an individual row):

```
def returnValuePoints(x, y):
    point = (x, y)
    col = int((point[0] - xOrigin) / pixelWidth)
    row = int((yOrigin - point[1] ) / pixelHeight)
    return (row, col)
```

Second you can call apply on the dataframe using axis=1 to be able to access the column values of each row:

```
val = df.apply(lambda x: returnValuePoints(x.geometry.x, x.geometry.y), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A warning about the code below: I haven't actually tested it, as I don't have access to a geopandas environment. However, I imagine it should work.

I don't think you actually want to use an apply here. Using geopandas methods, you can get a geopandas `GeoSeries` of points by applying some affine transformations:
First, you `translate` the series of points by `xOrigin, yOrigin`:

```
translated = df['geometry'].translate(xoff=-1*xOrigin, yoff=-1*yOrigin)
```

Then, you can both do the reflection about the x-axis and the scaling by `pixelWidth, pixelHeight` with a `scale`:

```
scaled_translated = translated.scale(xfact=1/pixelWidth, yfact=-1/pixelHeight)
```

Multiplying by -1 here does the reflection. If instead you mean to do `(point[1] - yOrigin)`, you can replace the -1 with 1.

This will give you a `GeoSeries`. If you want a series of *integer* point pairs, you'll have to do some more work. The code below will get you two integer `Series` with the x and y values (geopandas version > 0.3.0 required):

```
x_val = scaled_translated.x.astype(int)
y_val = scaled_translated.y.astype(int)
```

You can then, say, put them in your original data frame:

```
df['x_val'] = x_val
df['y_val'] = y_val
```

and if you *really* want a list of tuples (I think you probably shouldn't! You're loosing all the advantages of pandas!) you can do:

```
list(df[['x_val', 'y_val']].itertuples(index=False, name=None))
```

Answer (score -1):

I will show you one example.

```
import pandas as pd 

# reading csv 
s = pd.read_csv("stock.csv", squeeze = True) 

# defining function to check price 
def fun(num): 

    if num<200: 
        return "Low"

    elif num>= 200 and num<400: 
        return "Normal"

    else: 
        return "High"

# passing function to apply and storing returned series in new 
new = s.apply(fun) 

# printing first 3 element 
print(new.head(3)) 

# printing elements somewhere near the middle of series 
print(new[1400], new[1500], new[1600]) 

# printing last 3 elements 
print(new.tail(3))
```

[image: Here is the output]